# 3SUM with reversed outer loop

Tags: python, algorithm

There is known problem called [3SUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM).

Here is a little altered question: **Given an array S of n integers, find three integers in S such that the sum is closest to a given number, target.**

I'm trying to write code for it on two different sites with code-challenge problems. If I write outer loop from 0 and forward (as in wiki) I get accepted result on both sites. But if I write code as below (difference in outer loop and settings of "j" and "k") than on one of them I get wrong answer on some test case (I don't know it).
Could you tell me please if there is a problem in my code? It would be awesome to get input which causes wrong answer if code is really has mistake.

```python
def threeSumClosest(self, A, B):

    A.sort()

    closest = 1000000000

    if len(A) < 3:
        return closest

    for i in xrange(len(A)-1, 1, -1):
        j = 0
        k = i - 1
        while j < k:
            S = A[i] + A[j] + A[k]
            if S == B:
                return B
            elif S > B:
                if closest is None or abs(B - S) < abs(B - closest):
                    closest = S
                k -= 1
            else:
                if closest is None or abs(B - S) < abs(B - closest):
                    closest = S
                j += 1
    return closest
```

Comment: Have you tried feeding different (random) numbers through both versions of your algorithms and see where they differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, I think the test case where your code fails is a case where two right answers exist. Consider the following example:

`A = {1, 2, 3, 6, 10}` and `B = 16`

In this case, if you run the code with your current settings (outer loop starting from the end), then your code will output `17` which is `10 + 6 + 1`; however, with the "wiki" settings (outer loop starting from the beginning), the output would be `15` which is `10 + 2 + 3`. In both cases the difference between the answer and `B` is 1, but the numbers are different.

This could be easily checked: in your code, change the two conditions of `abs(B - S) < abs(B - closest)` to `abs(B - S) <= abs(B - closest)` (inside the `elif` and `else` statements). This will make sure that you would get the same answer as if you would have started from the beginning instead of the end in the outer loop. Make these two changes and resubmit your code, it should take care of it.

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right, I changed two conditions as you said and it passed all test cases. Thank you very much! :)